# what is the way to decide while creating new topic in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am planning to build a new alert system for forex data, I am consuming the data on websocket and planning to push it to kafka.

I am planning to support 15 currency pairs initially. what is the best way to push the data to kafka amd consume it later.

Should I create 15 topics each for currency pair separately so my consumer will only look for that currency data and match against the subscriptions and send the alerts.
OR 
Create one topic with 15 partitions and push the data to different partitions based on currency pair and have consumer reading dedicated partition?

Edit 1
Based on comments - I am elaborating it more,

I am planning to keep active subscription alerts in Redis or some in-memory db and then for every tick/data received from kafka, my consumer will check against the alerts in the redis and for whatever alert conditions match with the data, it will send the alert using notification service.
So in this case, I am thinking to have separate consumer for each currency pair which will do a comparison against only the subscriptions of that currency to increase the performance by checking only relevant data.
let me know if this is clear or more explanation is needed. Looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: could you please provide an example of alert logic

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to depend on a specific partition per currency.
regarding 15 topics or a single topic with multiple partitions (not partition per currency, just N partitions depending on data load and number of consumers) -  it depends whether you plan to handle currencies in the same way or different per each currency.
if logic will be the same and independent on currency, use a single topic.

Comment: I'd agree completely with Vasiliy - partitions are for scalability not for application logic. The only reason a producer has some control over which partition a message goes to is to help you avoid race conditions where ordered messages are consumed out of order by different consumers.

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi to give a example, Let's say I have 10K alerts on USD-EUR and another 10K alerts on USD-JPY currency pairs by different set of users for different currencies. If I configure specific consumer only reading the data of USD-EUR then I don't need to compare or even fetch it from redis all the other alerts to compare. This is my thought process so I was thinking to have partition or topic based on currency.

Comment: The problem with local caching like that is that although only a single consumer will read from a particular partition at any time, you can't know which consumer it is. A rebalance would probably mean a different consumer picking up that currency pair and it would have no access to any previously processed records

Comment: And you lose your ability to horizontally scale, which is one of Kafka's USPs

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply !
my consumer can get rebalance info using ConsumerRebalanceListener and then I can start comparing against new currency pair alerts that my consumer is getting. Does this makes sense? Also if you can suggest any approach that you have to handle this use case so I avoid comparing against all the alerts in the system irrespective of currency pair. Looking forward for your feedback.